# Multi-line regex support in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I notice the standard regex syntax for matching across multiple lines is to use /s, like so:

```
This is\nsome text
/This.*text/s
```

This works in Perl for instance but doesn't seem to be supported in Vim. Instead, I have to be much more specific:

```
/This[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*text/
```

I can't find any reason for why this should be, so I'm thinking I probably just missed the relevant bits in the vim help.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour one way or the other?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Yes, Perl's `//s` modifier isn't available on Vim regexes.  See `:h perl-patterns` for details and a list of other differences between Vim and Perl regexes.

Instead you can use `\_.`, which means "match any single character including newline".  It's a bit shorter than what you have.  See `:h /\_.`.

```
/This\_.*text/
```

Comment: Nice - my life just got a little easier. I'd been doing (.|\n)*

Comment: What does the forward slash in the `:h /\_.` do? I mean, I know it works, but why does `:h /\_.` work, and not `:h \_.` ?

Comment: @Eddified the forward slash (which is the default key for searching) specifies the context of `\_.` which you can read like: give me help for *the search expression* `\_.`

Comment: However, it seems that I can't perform lazy matching with this expression, even if I included it in parentheses? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @JIXiang For lazy match on `foo bar \n foo baz \n foo`, try `/foo\_.\{-}foo`