# Vim regex to find missing JSON element

Tags: regex, json, vim, vi

I have a big JSON file, formatted over multiple lines. I want to find objects that *don't* have a given property. The objects are guaranteed not to contain any further nested objects. Say the given property was `"bad"`, then I would want to locate the value of`"foo"` in the second element in the following (but not in the first element).

```
{
  result: [
    {
      "foo" : {
        "good" : 1,
        "bad" : 0
      },
      "bar" : 123
    },
    {
      "foo" : {
        "good" : 1
      },
      "bar" : 123
    }
  ]
}
```

I know about [multi-line regexes in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784176/multi-line-regex-support-in-vim) but I can't get anything that does what I want. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have to use Vim for this?  An actual JSON library would be a much better tool.

Comment: I agree with jwodder. If I were you, I'd just plop the JSON data into a variable of my browser's JS console, and walk through it's contents, logging the index wherever the element is missing.

Comment: @jwodder, @namuoi, I appreciate that this is probably the sensible option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/\v"foo"\_s*:\_s*\{%(%(\_[\t ,]"bad"\_s*:)@!\_.){-}\}
```

When you need to exclude something, you should look at negative look-aheads or look-behinds (latter is slower and unlike vim Perl/PCRE regular expressions do not support look-behinds except fixed-width (or a number of alternative fixed-width) ones).

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a [context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and as such is not regular. Unless you can give a much stricter set of rules to go on, no regex will be able to do what you want.

Comment: Sure, I'm not looking to parse arbitrary JSON, it's in exactly the format I've given above. The fields of `foo` do not contain any nested objects or braces of any kind, just key: number, key : number. I just want a greedy multi-line match of: `opening character`, `anything that doesn't include a given word`, `closing character`...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is:

`/\(foo\_.\{-}bad\)\@!foo`

Best regards!