# Multi-line regex in Vim: filtering out blocks of text in a file

Tags: regex, vim

What is the correct regex for filtering multiple-lined blocks of text that end with `#tags`? My file looks like this:

```
Text block 1:
- something
- something
- something
#tag1 #tag2

Text block 2:
- somethingelse
- somethingelse
#tag2

Text block 3:
- really interesting stuff
- really interesting stuff
#tag1

etc
```

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784176/multi-line-regex-support-in-vim) [great tips](http://blog.vinceliu.com/2007/12/regular-expression-matching-more-than.html) pointed me to using `\_.`. Hence, for filtering out both blocks containing `#tag1`, I came up with this:

```
\_.\{-}#tag1.*
```

That, however, only gives me Text block 1. Instead of pointing me further to Text block 2 (which also contains the tag), the cursor starts moving downwards line-by-line.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any explanations!

---

**EDIT**: A follow-up on how to create a multi-command for this kind of query is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596502/vim-multi-command-for-filtering-out-blocks-of-text).

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to match text block 1 and text block 3, but not text block 2, is that correct?

Comment: @F J -- yes, this is correct. Block 1 and block 2 contain #tag1 which I want to filter out.

Comment: But Block 2 doesn't contain #tag1...

Comment: Yes, which is why I'd like to get it out of my sight. :) As a non-native English speaker I used "filtering out", which, I guess, we understood differently in this case. I apologize for possible confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me if you want to match every line in the block (use to yank all text in the matching blocks into a buffer)

```
^\(.\+\n\)\{-}#.*tag1
```

So you could do

```
g/^\(.\+\n\)\{-}#.*tag1/d A
```

To delete all text blocks(change d to y if you want to yank them instead, of course) that end with a #tag1 and yank them into register A, then `"ap` to paste them all (or `<C-r>a` in insert mode)

This lets me jump to the first line of each block that ends with tags containing tag1.

```
\(\%^\|^\n\)\zs.\(.\+\n\)\{-}#.*tag1.*$
```

The problem with

```
\_.\{-}#tag1.*
```

Is that while you're using {-} to be non-greedy, it's still always going to match as long as there is a line that has #tag1 below the current line that you're on.  Using _.* or _.{-} can be pretty dangerous.  For example when you are on the line "Text block 2:"

```
Text block 2:
- somethingelse
- somethingelse
#tag2

Text block 3:
- really interesting stuff
- really interesting stuff
#tag1
```

You get a match for the entire range Text block 2 until #tag1 after text block 3.

If instead you had

```
Text block 3:
- really interesting stuff
- really interesting stuff
#tag1

Text block 2:
- somethingelse
- somethingelse
#tag2
```

You would only match lines in Text block 3.

Comment: Excellent, this does the job. Thank you! However -- how could I **copy the Text Block + the empty line below it?** I've tried adding `\n`s to the end of the regex but that's not it.

Comment: That's really tricky because the search relies pretty heavily on those newlines existing in order to differentiate between different blocks.  What I would do is after pasting all of the code that matches the regex, run a global search and replace with `s/^#.*tag1.*\n/&\r` to put a newline after every line that has a tag1.  You could get fancy and only do that if there wasn't a newline already there, but that's a whole new question :p

Comment: Brilliant! I was trying to figure out this replacement myself but the `&` is what I left out. Still new to Vim, what can you do. Thanks mate! Now I'll just join all the steps into one `:SearchTags` command.

Comment: I encoutered a problem while trying define a command with this expression. See my answer below. Can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: @mart I'd be happy to take a look if you posted your question as a separate question, but posting another answer on the question isn't really the right way to get help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm obviously a SO-novice :-) I modified the original question accordingly.

Comment: @mart haha don't worry about it, it's no big deal.  However, typically when you find yourself typing "Question 2"(or "Question 3" :p) you should go ahead and make another question.  Remember that we're trying to build a huge knowledge base of answered questions, so 3 specific, short questions is more valuable than one long, multipronged question.  Additionally, how better to motivate people to answer your questions than with more reputation? :p

Comment: OK, I cleaned up the question and created another, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076834/multi-line-regex-in-vim-filtering-out-blocks-of-text-in-a-file).