# How to construct a multi-command for filtering out blocks of text in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim, command, tagging, multiline

This is a follow-up to my [question about using multi-line regex in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076834/multi-line-regex-in-vim-filtering-out-blocks-of-text-in-a-file).

A quick explanation: I have blocks of text tagged with `#tags` and separated by a blank line. I want to filter out all blocks that include a specific tag. I was helped with regex here (thanks!), so I constructed the following command:

```
command -nargs=1 TagSearch g/^\(.\+\n\)\{-}.*#<args>.*/y a | vnew | put a | %s/^#.*<args>.*\n/&\r
```

Hence, doing a `:TagSearch tag` should:

1. Search for the `#tag`.
2. Paste **all** corresponding Text Blocks into a new vertical buffer.
3. Add a blank line between the Text Blocks in the new buffer.

**Q1**: When I do each step separately, everything works. But the multi-command **only pastes the first matching text block** into the new buffer. Why?

**Q2**: How could I make the command accept multiple arguments (in case I want to search for several `#tags` at once)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the following implementation.

```
command! -nargs=* -bar TagSearch call CollectParagraphs([<f-args>])

function! CollectParagraphs(tags) range
    let tags = len(a:tags) > 0 ? a:tags : [expand('<cword>')]
    let pats = map(copy(tags), '"\\.\\*#" . escape(v:val, "\\")')

    let v = winsaveview()
    let [sr, @/; lines] = [@/, '\V' . join(pats, '\&')]
    g//call extend(lines, getline(search('\n\n\zs', 'bnW'), line("'}")))
    let @/ = sr
    call winrestview(v)

    exe 'vnew' escape(join(tags), ' %#|\')
    set buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
    call setline(1, lines)
endfunction
```

Comment: Two more additions, though. 1. how could I pass `<cword>` as an argument here? 2. Could the new buffer also have query words as its name? (E.g. the results would display in a buffer named `word1-word2-...-wordn` in case of multiple search words.) Thanks again!

Comment: @mart:  Please take a look at the updated answer.  (Sorry for such a long delay in responding.)  The new version of the command I wrote additionally supports both of the features you would like to have.  Tags that were searched for are included into the title of a buffer displaying search results.  To search for the tag under the cursor, issue the `:TagSearch` command without arguments.

Comment: This is really awesome, sincere thanks! I have been using your previous implementation with pleasure literally every day (I'm working on a book). However: I recorded a macro that lists all the tags found from the current file in a new vertical "tags buffer". How could I now **search through the current file with a `cword` from the "tags buffer"**? (This is, of course, not an essential feature; the system is already really nice, but, hey, I'd save a few more keystrokes! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a good old play around with this and learnt quite a bit in the process! Looks like there are a few problems going on here.

Here's how I worked through to get it working, although as there are so many approaches with vim there is probably a tidier way somehow.

The g command is of the form g/pattern/command. What I think was happening was in your original form, the | vnew | put a | %s... part of the command was being executed linewise with the g command, rather than once as part of the TagSearch command. I changed the g command to being 'executed' instead which solves the problem - I'd be interested to know if there is a way to specify what the pipe applies to without using execute, I couldnt get it working (brackets don't work for example). This would have been why you were only getting the first line. This gives us (fixing a typo in your '%s' command):

```
command! -nargs=1 TagSearch execute 'g/^\(.\+\n\)\{-}.*#<args>.*/y a' | vnew | put a | %s/^.*#<args>.*\n/&\r
```

This seems to reverse the problem though, and we now only get the last line in the new buffer. The other problem with the g command, is that when you do /y a, it overwrites the a register each time. There is a way to get vim to append to a register instead, using the capitalized register name (/y A) (see :help quotea). Doing it this way we need to initialize the register to blank first, using let. That gives us this:

```
command! -nargs=1 TagSearch let @a='' | execute 'g/^\(.\+\n\)\{-}.*#<args>.*/y A' | vnew | put a | %s/^.*#<args>.*\n/&\r
```

Finally to get it to execture with multiple tags, I just fiddled with the `<args>` a bit (calling TagSearch tag1 tag2, args would literally be the string 'tag1 tag2') to get it to fit in the regex as below:

```
command! -nargs=* TagSearch let @a='' | execute 'g/^\(.\+\n\)\{-}.*#\(' . substitute('<args>', ' ', '\\|', 'g') . '\).*/y A' | vnew | put a | execute '%s/^.*#\(' . substitute('<args>', ' ', '\\|', 'g') . '\).*\n/&\r'
```

If you add any more features to this you might want to try playing around with a little vimscript function or something instead, otherwise it might get pretty hard to maintain! You'd be able to grab your text blocks into nice lists and potentially process them a bit more easily rather than having to do everything as if you were actually typing. Take a look at :help functions for things that are available (although there may be a better starting point in the help for vimscript somewhere else).

Comment: I was just playing around with \& too. Had a bit of success using the 'finding two words in either order' tip on here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_patterns (although I had to leave out the angle brackets \< and \> as they were causing issues with the # in the tag name), but unfortunately it breaks your nice multi line grab pattern :-(

Comment: +1. Thanks, your solution works great. However, I would like 
`:TagSearch foo bar` to filter out blocks that contain *both* keywords, not only one. But why does replacing `\\|` with `\\&` give an error? Other than that, as a Vim novice and non-coder, I highly appreciate this kind of comprehensive explaining. I'd like to create a (maybe clickable) list from my #tags (without using :helptags). So yeah, vimscript must introduce itself to me soon :-)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I guess I'll just make a second query on the initial search results then. That's ok, though not as elegant :-)