# Find and replace everything between curly braces in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace everything between curly braces (including the curly braces) with ; character.
For example:

```
void my_function(void){
   <function code>
}
```

ends as:

```
void my_function(void);
```

I have tried `:%s/{\_.*}/;/gc` regex after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784176/multi-line-regex-support-in-vim) answer but it selects the text from the first { to the last }, I need to make it stop in each } to select curly braces pairs each time

Comment: Just in case it is useful to someone I managed to do what I was looking for with regex:     :%s/{\\_.\{-}}/;/cg

Comment: regexp is probably not the right way to do it as it does not support nested parenthesis search. You woud need recursion and I doubt that vim supports it. The best way is to do a vim script. You can use `d%` to delete the matching curly brace. EDIT: Be also careful, because lists use curly braces and you probably don't want them to be removed!

Comment: The answer provided by the link above does NOT answer the question of @jap-jap. The solution he is looking for is probably this: `:g/^[A-Za-z0-9: \t]\+([^)]*)\s*{/norm f{d%a;`

Comment: Maybe tyis way: `g/){/normal 0f{di{`

Comment: `di{` keeps both curly braces and it doesn't replace them by a semicolumn. But otherwise nice for the `){`simplification. I would still add a \s* thought: `:g/)\s*{/norm f{d%a;`